# How to change the status bar color in flutter app, only in one page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to change the status bar color of the app in specific page.

used code:

```
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor:Colors.white, 
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
      ))
```

above will change the color, but how to do that just for the specific page, I am using navigator. for navigation.

Comment: or better set the statusBarColor to transparent  and then set scaffold color of your choice which will make status bar color too the same and in your specific page in which you want set a different color set a background color that you want for status bar

Comment: U mean default status bar color transparent and scaffold background color I should change is it ?

Comment: yes, that's what i said.

Comment: Okay will try..

Comment: Seems like your trick is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your code just above the build method of every page you create.

So for one scaffold, call this above the scaffold’s build method to change the status bar color to grey

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white, 
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
))
```

To change it back for another screen, simply recall the code with a different color above that screen’s scaffold’s build method:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black, 
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
    ))
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @s.am.i could you explain your question more thoroughly? What I have provided will let you control the status bar color on individual screens but not other ones

Comment: According to your method, that's correct we can manipulate the color, 
imagine there are 5 screen on the flow then if u change the color on page 2 that will effect to page 3 if u change the color on that it will effect the next, so I need a better way to handle it, instead of using  everywhere

Comment: Redeclaring the statement before each scaffold is declared will change the color for that screen, and therefore no color will stick for another screen. Give it a go, I've used it and it is functional

Comment: Imagine the case where you put it in a screen that pushes another screen with another status bar color, then you pop the current screen, it will change the color of the status bar for both screens.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this isn’t the case as you when a new screen is pushed, the code to change it is run in the build function of that screen. I guess it’s a matter of wether system chrome affects the scaffold you are building or the entire system (as the name implies I guess, you could easily be correct here)